# How to optimize MySQL query for a large database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've noticed a serious problem recently, when my database increased to over 620000 records. Following query:

```
SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS `time` FROM `log` WHERE (`projectname`="test" OR `projectname` IS NULL)  ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

has an execution time about 2,5s on a local database. I was wondering how can I speed it up?

The EXPLAIN commands produces following output:

```
ID: 1
select type: SIMPLE
TABLE: log
type: ref_or_null
possible_keys: projectname
key: projectname
key_len: 387
ref: const
rows: 310661
Extra: Using where; using filesort
```

I've got indexes set on projectname, time columns.

Any help?

EDIT: Thanks to ypercube response, I was able to decrease query execution time. But when I only add another condition to WHERE clause (AND severity="changes") it lasts 2s again. Is it a good solution to include all of the possible "WHERE" columns to my merged-index?

```
ID: 1 
select type: SIMPLE 
TABLE: log 
type: ref_or_null 
possible_keys: projectname 
key: projectname 
key_len: 419 
ref: const, const 
rows: 315554 
Extra: Using where; using filesort
```

Table structure:

```
   CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `projectname` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `master` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `itemName` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `severity` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'info',
  `message` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `more` TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `projectname` (`severity`,`projectname`,`time`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=621691 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: it has to sort all 620000 records before getting to take the top 20. If you have that index on `time`, maybe you can add a `time > _sometime_` in the `where` clause to limit the result set before ordering?

Comment: Instead of * use actual column name which are going to be use .... that will speed up your query...

Comment: How many rows pass the condition `(projectname = 'test' OR projectname IS NULL)` ?

Comment: I appears that projectname of test or null covers most rows on the table. As it appears to be dealing with about half the rows on the table I am a bit surprised MySQL has used the index, but that still leaves it sorting 300k records. Can you narrow the rows down further (ie, maybe looking at a limited time range)? By the way, when you say about the indexes, do you have a covering index on both projectname and time, or just individual indexes on each? Not sure if an index on time helps when you are sorting on a field that is the same name for both the original field and the alias.

Comment: Rony: I'm going to use all of the columns, so does it make a difference if I would type all column names instead of a "*"?

Comment: ypercube: The result is 621489 records.

Comment: Using SELECT * probably won't slow things down if you are using all the columns although it might a bit if you are only using some of the columns. However it is generally a bad idea for maintenance reasons (and in this case you have 2 returned columns which want to have the same name, both called time)

Comment: Possibly adding the extra column has prevented mysql using the covering index, or triggered it to use an index on severity instead (leaving it to manually sort on the time again). Can you check the EXPLAIN again for the amended query?

Comment: ID: 1
select type: SIMPLE
TABLE: log
type: ref_or_null
possible_keys: projectname
key: projectname
key_len: 419
ref: const, const
rows: 315554
Extra: Using where; using filesort

Comment: Can you also add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE log;` output in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index on `(projectname, time)`:

```
ALTER TABLE log
  ADD INDEX projectname_time_IX            -- choose a name for the index
    (projectname, time) ;
```

And then use the original column for the `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) AS unix_time 
FROM log 
WHERE (projectname = 'test' OR projectname IS NULL)  
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20 ;
```

or this variation - to make sure that the index is used effectively:

```
  ( SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) AS unix_time 
    FROM log 
    WHERE projectname = 'test'
    ORDER BY time DESC 
    LIMIT 20 
  )
  UNION ALL 
  ( SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) AS unix_time 
    FROM log 
    WHERE projectname IS NULL
    ORDER BY time DESC 
    LIMIT 20 
  ) 
  ORDER BY time DESC
  LIMIT 20 ;
```

Comment: When I have one index set to both columns (projectname, time) time was reduced down to 1s

Comment: And with the last version? Still in 1 second? Sounds too much for just 20 rows.

Comment: Well, that is strange. I check that results in two places and yes, your solution significantly improved query time. First solution takes about 0.039s, second one is better, about 0.023s. But still, on my browser this ajax response runs for ~1s (2,5s in the beginning).

Comment: Well, that time also depends on how the browser is connected to the database, if a new connection is setup for every query (and then closed) or not and probably a few other things I'm unaware of.

Comment: @ypercube - ` Sounds too much for just 20 rows` that is of course not true. It _does_ sort the complete result set before it returns the top 20, so we might be dealing with 2 times 320000 records in your union example. I _still_ agree that it should not take too long :)

Comment: My second query uses the index for sorting the 2 internal subqueries and then the external query has only 40 rows to sort.

Comment: @oerkelens - It should only be unioning 2 sets of 20 records as the subqueries have limit clauses on them. And the subqueries should be fairly quick as they both should be able to retrieve the records sorted into order directly from the index.

Comment: Yeah, that could be true. But there is another question now. My app reacts on different filters, so my query may look like in my edited post with only difference of an extra column in where clause. Adding another index I have a situation like this => (projectname, severity, time) but it doesn't seem to help, I get still 2 seconds...

Comment: Correction: My second query uses the index to (not sort at all but) select the Top 20 in the 2 internal subqueries and then the external query has only 40 rows to sort.

Comment: @user2305130 Try rewriting the queries as my example above, removing the `OR` and using 2 subqueries instead. Queries with many `OR` are not the best thing the optimizer can deal with.

Comment: Have you added another index on projectname, severity, time, or just amended the existing index? If you have added a new one I would expect it to chose the better index depending on whether you are checking severity or not. If you have just changed the existing index then I would think it would help when severity is specified but would render the index useless when severity is not specified.

Comment: What @Kickstar says. And the index on `(severity, projectname, time)` will be preferable than `(projectname, severity, time)`

Comment: I have amended to the existing one. I have also changed the position (moved "severity" to the beginning) and I hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Can you post the updated query you are now using in the original question?